# Dynamically calculated the sum of a filtered column on another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in Excel.

On one sheet, I have a table containing a date, a description and a number value.

For example:

```
1/11/2014 Groceries 23.54
1/12/2014 Dining    36.99
1/18/2014 Groceries 45.55
1/20/2014 Movies    12.99
1/20/2014 Dining    40.24
```

In my second sheet, I want to have a row that dynamically calculates the sum of all the values with the a specific description.

```
Groceries : 69.09
Dining : 77.23
Movies : 12.99
```

Is there a way to do this without VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use following formula (suppose that your data (Groceries,Dining,..) in sheet1 are in `B1:B50` range, their number values in column `C`, and in sheet2 your data (Groceries, Dining,..) starts from `A1`):

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$50,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$C$1:$C$50)
```

just write it in sheet2 in `B1` cell and stretch it down

Answer (score 2):

`SUMIF` is what you're after. It takes 3 arguments:

- range of cells where you keep your descriptions,
- the specific description you want the values to be added up,
- range of cells with the actual numeric values.

To access another sheet's data, use `SheetName!` before cell's/range's address.